# Add the values of a text field into an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, android-spinner

I need to add the values typed into the textfield into an array list.

I implemented it as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 Spinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3;
 Button add;
 EditText subject;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 // Spinner element
   spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
   spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
   spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
   add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

// Spinner click listener

   //spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   //spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
               int position, long id) {
           // On selecting a spinner item
           String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

           // Showing selected spinner item
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   "Selected Subject : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }
   });
   add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


     Context context;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String content;
         content = subject.getText().toString();
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(content);
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            ListIterator it = list.listIterator();

           it.hasNext();

    }
   });



    }
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
            //do something here
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            //optionally do something here
        }
    });
  }
```

But , every time I enter a new value in the text field the previous value is overwritten. How do I use arrays to implement this? every time I enter a value I want it to be saved separately in the drop down menu.

Comment: Is this code placed into the `afterTextChanged()` of your `EditText`? If not, can you show us where these lines are placed in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous value is overwritten because you always adding new `list` instance into `adapter`. 
So make list instance only once,i.e. globally in your activity.i.e. add this line

```
 List list = new ArrayList();
```

below to

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 Spinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3;
 Button add;
 EditText subject;
```

And use below code in your `onClick` function. as

```
 String content;
            content = subject.getText().toString();
           list.add(content);
            ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because everytime you have a new value, you create a new ArrayList (List list = new ArrayList();)and then add to it. Make the list a member variable and then try adding it.